# windows file path convert to mac

Tags: javascript, macos, windows-7-x64

At work I receive email with a file path to our T drive. As I use a mac in our office the file path is slightly different.

An example email may be:

> find your work files at
>
> T:\Folder\Course\Subject\Year\Month\file.txt

On my mac I would have to go to

```
/Username/T/Folder/Course/Subject/Year/Month/file.txt
```

Normally if I am working on my windows machine I can copy and paste this file location into the windows explorer, and the file/folder will open. But if I copy and paste this into mac finder "go to folder" it doesn't like it.

1. Is it possible to write a script on my mac to convert this string?
2. Is there another way to be able to get to this file path quicker rather than manually clicking through folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

```
echo 'T:\Folder\Course\Subject\Year\Month\file.txt' | sed 's/\\/\//g'
=> T:/Folder/Course/Subject/Year/Month/file.txt
```

If you don't want to run this command everytime, you could create a file `/usr/bin/openWinPath` with these contents:

```
path=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/\\/\//g')
open "$path"
```

Then run `chmod +x /usr/bin/openWinPath` in a terminal to make the script executable, and you should be able to use

```
openWinPath "T:\Folder\Course\Subject\Year\Month\file.txt"
```

in your terminal

Hope that's what you needed!